# Show distinct column values in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

With pyspark dataframe, how do you do the equivalent of Pandas `df['col'].unique()`.

I want to list out all the unique values in a pyspark dataframe column.

Not the SQL type way (registertemplate then SQL query for distinct values).

Also I don't need `groupby` then `countDistinct`, instead I want to check distinct VALUES in that column.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Let's assume we're working with the following representation of data (two columns, `k` and `v`, where `k` contains three entries, two unique:

```
+---+---+
|  k|  v|
+---+---+
|foo|  1|
|bar|  2|
|foo|  3|
+---+---+
```

With a Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
p_df = pd.DataFrame([("foo", 1), ("bar", 2), ("foo", 3)], columns=("k", "v"))
p_df['k'].unique()
```

This returns an `ndarray`, i.e. `array(['foo', 'bar'], dtype=object)`

You asked for a "pyspark dataframe alternative for pandas df['col'].unique()". Now, given the following Spark dataframe:

```
s_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("foo", 1), ("bar", 2), ("foo", 3)], ('k', 'v'))
```

If you want the *same* result from Spark, i.e. an `ndarray`, use `toPandas()`:

```
s_df.toPandas()['k'].unique()
```

Alternatively, if you don't need an `ndarray` specifically and just want a list of the unique values of column `k`:

```
s_df.select('k').distinct().rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]).collect()
```

Finally, you can also use a list comprehension as follows:

```
[i for i in s_df.select('k').distinct().collect()]
```

Comment: Hi eddies, the last code line distinct().map() didn't worked for me. Error:AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'.  I am on spark 2.0. And toPandas thing, i will not say it is an alternative, it converts spark dataframe to pandas dataframe first then doing pandas operation on it.

Comment: Hi satya. Just updated the answer by adding a `.rdd` call after `distinct()`. It worked without that in Spark 1.6.2, but I just confirmed that the edited answer works in Spark 2.0.0 as well.

Comment: Why try to avoid spark dataframe operations by converting to a pandas dataframe (hurts if its gigantic) or utilizing rdd operations when spark dataframes are perfectly capable of doing this? see below answer of @Pabbati

Comment: @Laurens There were three solutions in the answer above, depending on what the poster really wanted. In all cases, the poster wanted some form of a list/array of the distinct values (c.f. poster's response to seufagner's answer). The third solution above does use Spark's dataframe api just as Pabbati's answer but actually returns a list, as per the poster's requirements.

Comment: The question specifically asks how to "show" unique values of a dataframe column. I think @Pabbati 's answer does this effectively: df.select('column1').distinct().show()

Comment: Yes, the question title includes the word "show". But the poster specifically clarified that SEEing the results wasn't adequate and wanted a list. As mentioned above, see the poster's comment to seufagner's answer.

Comment: good point. i suggested an edit to the question to ask for a list instead of to show the results.

Comment: `[i.k for i in s_df.select('k').distinct().collect()]` ;I have a doubt. I only have column name in string format (for example 'k'). Is there any way to write `i.k` when I only have string column name.  Actually column name is taken as a user input. That's why I'm asking this

Answer (score 402):

This should help to get distinct values of a column:

```
df.select('column1').distinct().collect()
```

Note that `.collect()` doesn't have any built-in limit on how many values can return so this might be slow -- use `.show()` instead or add `.limit(20)` before `.collect()` to manage this.

Comment: this code returns data that's not iterable, i.e. I see the distinct data bit am not able to iterate over it in code. Any other way that enables me to do it. I tried using toPandas() to convert in it into Pandas df and then get the iterable with unique values. However, running into '' Pandas not found' error message

Comment: @Abhi: inplace of .show() instead do a .collect(), that way you will get a iterable of all the distinct values of that particular column. But make sure your master node have enough memory to keep hold of those unique values, because collect will push all the requested data(in this case unique values of column) to master Node  :)

Comment: To obtain a Python **list of actual values** and not `Row` objects, you need to use a list comprehension like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60896261/7465462

Comment: df.select('column').distinct().collect().toPandas().column.to_list()

Comment: `pyspark_df.select(target_column_name).distinct().toPandas()[target_column_name].to_list()` will give a flat python list.

Comment: In case you don't want to use pandas, you can also use a flat map function to convert it into a python flat list: ```pyspark_df.select(target_column_name).distinct().rdd.flatMap(list).collect()```

Answer (score 26):

You can use `df.dropDuplicates(['col1','col2'])` to get only distinct rows based on colX in the array.

Comment: @seufagner-yes I can do a df.dropDuplictes(['col1']) to see (mark SEE ) the unique values, but without a collect(to_rdd or to pandas DF then df['col'].unique()), I can't get the unique values list. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: The user did not ask how to display non duplicate values.. He just wanted to get a list of all unique/distinct items, which includes duplicates too!

Comment: This is correct because df.select(<column name>).collect() is an expensive operation which may lead to stage failure error.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to see the distinct values of a specific column in your dataframe, you would just need to write the following code. It would show the 100 distinct values (if 100 values are available) for the `colname` column in the `df` dataframe.

```
df.select('colname').distinct().show(100, False)
```

If you want to do something fancy on the distinct values, you can save the distinct values in a vector:

```
a = df.select('colname').distinct()
```

Answer (score 14):

`collect_set` can help to get unique values from a given column of `pyspark.sql.DataFrame`:

```
df.select(F.collect_set("column").alias("column")).first()["column"]
```

Comment: I agree on using `collect_set`, but I think the following would be cleaner:

```df.agg(F.collect_set("column")).collect()[0][0]```

Answer (score 12):

you could do

```py
distinct_column = 'somecol' 

distinct_column_vals = df.select(distinct_column).distinct().collect()
distinct_column_vals = [v[distinct_column] for v in distinct_column_vals]
```

Comment: This is amazingly simple, thank you

Comment: Just a quick comment: since you already selected `distinct_column` in the first line, you don't need to repeat it below. You can just do `[v[0] for v in distinct_column_vals]`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the [`dropDuplicates`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates) option there is the method named as we know it in [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) [`drop_duplicates`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.drop_duplicates):

> **drop_duplicates()** is an alias for **dropDuplicates()**.

**Example**

```
s_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("foo", 1),
                                   ("foo", 1),
                                   ("bar", 2),
                                   ("foo", 3)], ('k', 'v'))
s_df.show()

+---+---+
|  k|  v|
+---+---+
|foo|  1|
|foo|  1|
|bar|  2|
|foo|  3|
+---+---+
```

---

**Drop by subset**

```
s_df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['k']).show()

+---+---+
|  k|  v|
+---+---+
|bar|  2|
|foo|  1|
+---+---+
s_df.drop_duplicates().show()


+---+---+
|  k|  v|
+---+---+
|bar|  2|
|foo|  3|
|foo|  1|
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar to other answer, but the question doesn't seem to want Row objects returned, but instead actual values.

The ideal one-liner is
`df.select('column').distinct().collect().toPandas().column.to_list()`
assuming that running the .collect() isn't going to be too big for memory.

I recommend a `df.select('column').distinct().count()` first to estimate size, and make sure it's not too huge beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to select ALL(columns) data as distinct frrom a DataFrame (df), then

`df.select('*').distinct().show(10,truncate=False)`

Answer (score 2):

Run this first

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
```

Then run

```
spark.sql("""
    SELECT distinct
        column name
    FROM
        df
    """).show()
```

Comment: THe query is not to use SQL syntax within pyspark. A pure pyspark way of distinct was the ask.

Answer (score 2):

I find this to be the most intuitive (i.e., similar to Pandas) syntax:

```
new_df = df[['col']].distinct() # returns a one-column pyspark dataframe
```

or

```
new_col = df[['col']].distinct()['col'] # returns a pyspark column object.
```

So to get those to a list you need:

```
new_list = df[['col']].distinct().rdd.map(lambda row: row.col).collect()
```

Answer (score 2):

This one-liner will give you a list of unique values:

```
unique_list = [i['col_name'] for i in df.select('col_name').distinct().collect()]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be helpful

```
df.select(collect_set("your column")).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that your original DataFrame is called `df`. Then, you can use:

```py
df1 = df.groupBy('column_1').agg(F.count('column_1').alias('trip_count'))
df2 = df1.sort(df1.trip_count.desc()).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this :

```py
unique_values = df.select("col").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
print(unique_values)
```